# Has my Google Chrome gone scareware?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, malware

I can't visit http://www.opengl.org on Google Chrome 6.0.472.63 without the Malware Detected warning

> **Warning: Visiting this site may harm your computer!**
>
> The website at
>   **www.opengl.org** appears to host malware
>   – software that can hurt your computer
>   or otherwise operate without your
>   consent. Just visiting a site that
>   hosts malware can infect your
>   computer. For detailed information
>   about the problems with this site,
>   visit the Google Safe Browsing
>   diagnostic page for www.opengl.org.diagnostic page for www.opengl.org.

This is stifling productivity, and as far as I'm concerned I'm not going to be downloading any `PlayThisEpicGame.EXE` file anytime soon.

*To add to the hilarity, loading a new tab is screwed as well! haha*
[image: run zombies!]

Is anyone else experiencing this on the OpenGL website, or is my Chrome a little drunk? Is there a whitelist I can enter sites that I don't want this warning on. I don't want to disable malware blocking just to get my GL on.

Extensions:

- AdBlock
- Feedly
- Slideshow
- Smooth Scroll
- Speed Dial

On Windows 7 32-Bit, updated Avast! AV.

Comment: It's not just you. Mac OS X 10.6, latest Chrome.

Comment: I've globally disabled the warning via `Wrench > Options > Enable phishing and malware protection`. Pressing Ctrl + T and getting that is just madness..

Comment: I'm using Firefox and getting the same message.

Comment: Getting the same on Chrome 7.0.517 on Mac OS X 10.6.3

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You *could* check the handy box and click "Proceed anyway"... But I recommend you figure out **why** the site was blacklisted first.

The site could have been the victim of a hack and may very well be serving malware that the moment or the recent past.  Such blacklists are usually cleared quickly once the site is restored.

If your DNS resolution has been messed with (like by malware you may have already contracted) you may not actually be going to the site you think you are.  Try using a web based lookup service to resolve the IP and compare to the one you get from the nslookup command on your box.

Comment: +1 for not assuming a legitimate site hasn't been hacked.

Comment: "Proceed anyway" works, but it comes up every time I go to another link from that site. +1 for DNS, never gave that one a thought.

Comment: Example: ThePirateBay was using an Advertising site that was blocked. For a few days every visit gave that warning. "Good" site thats now linked/serving "bad" stuff.

Comment: @WemerCD: The pirate bay was never really a safe place to be in general.

Answer (score 19):

It's not your Chrome, it's the Google safe browsing database which contains [an entry for opengl.org](http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=opengl.org):

> Of the 22 pages we tested on the site over the past 90 days, 1 page(s) resulted in malicious software being downloaded and installed without user consent. The last time Google visited this site was on 2010-09-23, and the last time suspicious content was found on this site was on 2010-09-23.
>
> Malicious software includes 1 exploit(s). Successful infection resulted in an average of 2 new process(es) on the target machine.
>
> Malicious software is hosted on 1 domain(s), including hthexhe.co.cc/.
>
> 1 domain(s) appear to be functioning as intermediaries for distributing malware to visitors of this site, including dbkzbkz.co.cc/.
>
> This site was hosted on 1 network(s) including AS21844 (THEPLANET).

Answer (score 14):

I'd like to add that Google's warning is not nonsense. Yesterday I was navigating opengl.org  on an XP machine (via Chrome), when suddenly I got two alerts from my antivirus (Avira) about malware being found in the browser's temporary directory. I wasn't visiting any other websites at that moment.